# Runnable not working properly

Tags: android, handler, runnable

```
      public void delay() { //give delay before comp can  play
      Handler handler = new Handler();
       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startPlay();
        }
       }, 1500);
   }
```

I made a game having nine buttons such that a player can play against the phone. Each of these buttons calls the delay method above to create a delay between when the player played and when the phone is given a chance to play but as I test the game sometimes the delay is fine but sometimes I notice that the delay is very short as if a call to the delay method has not been made. I would like to know why its happening like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since, all of your buttons are calling the same method `startPlay()` after a delay of `1500` ms, I don't think you'd be able to differentiate between the delay caused by individual buttons.

Assume you've 2 buttons, Button1 and Button2 and Button3. When Button1 is clicked, a delay of 1500ms happens and then immediately (after 1sec) you press Button2. So a new handler is created which will again have a delay of 1500ms. But now the delay for the Button1 is over and `startPlay()` would execute. Now this `startPlay()` belongs to Button1 and not Button2. Button2's `startPlay()` will be called after 500ms(1500ms - 1sec).

Comment: The thing is if i press say Button1, a call to the delay method is made which cause a delay between when i pressed Button1 and the time that the phone gets a chance to play. Once i press Button1 i all the buttons are inactive until when the phone has played i.e i only get the chance to play again once the computer has played.

Comment: Can you log the time before and after the delay? Log `System.currenttimemillis()` when the user clicks the button and then again in the `run()` method. The difference between the 2 logs should be of 1500ms. You can also log the difference and see if its different

Comment: I just did that and the difference i got was 1501

Comment: That is perfect then. Thats what it is supposed to be right? Note that 1500 is in milliseconds. So essentially you're waiting for 1.5s.

Comment: if (j == 0) {
            buttonC3.setClickable(false);       //comp chance to play prevent user playing twice before comp play
            buttonC2.setClickable(false);
            buttonC1.setClickable(false);
            buttonB1.setClickable(false);
           
        } 
            
        }
    }

Comment: But still there comes a time when the delay seems to be almost zero and that worries me.

Comment: Can you print the logs each time and see where you're going wrong? Ideally the log should always print 1500.

Comment: To set disable the other buttons i use button.Clickable(false) and when the phone returns the chance to the player it sets the button.Clickable(true). I tested it in the debugger and they only respond once the phone has played.